# Is a question seeking for an English word for a new terminology on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, terminology

I'm a grad student pursuing Master's degree. Though I'm unsure this counts as a research (it has a serious motivation, though), yet I was playing with point-set topology, and I made my own new terminology. Namely:

> Given a topological space $X$ and its subset $A$, the set $A \cap \overline{X \setminus A}$ is said to be the **curtain** of $A$.

Though I'm happy with this terminology, I'm afraid because, (1) I'm unsure whether other people will intuitively understand it, and (2) there might be another time when I'd have a hard time seeking for an appropriate terminology.

Is Math SE a good place for questions like?:

- What would an appropriate English word for this new notion I made be?
- This is my proposed terminology for this new notion I made. Is there a better word?

Comment: My opinion is no; this is more like an artistic question. Its different if you are asking about a known concept and you want to know what people *already* call it. This has a definite answer

Comment: @CalvinKhor Would ELL SE be an appropriate place then?

Comment: That's not a site I'm familliar with so I don't know, sorry. But I will add, you could try the chat rooms, e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: There is nothing wrong with improvising your own terminology provided you supply a definition for your Readers (as I'm sure you would).  There are related questions you might have about the concept that could be on-topic, but inasmuch as you are free to introduce new names, there is no definite answer as @CalvinKhor notes on what you should call it.  That said, you might use [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to locate previous posts that use that math expression.

Comment: I can foresee a problem if every graduate student created their own lexicon; doing so will not improve understanding, but undermine it, as it would require each thesis writer who chooses to create unique concepts, to include a "glossary", of self-named concepts, when there already are well-established concepts that currently exist.  Do you want to be understood, or do you want to insist every understand your "new math?"

Comment: @DannyuNDos English Language Learners SE is for getting help with learning English for non-native speakers, so getting advice on creating new academic jargon is way beyond that site's remit. Does this 'curtain' have some special significance?

Comment: @OliverHouse it looks to be the part of the boundary inside the original set.